# change one function into second in button click

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Hi I have array with years in my controller:

```
public function getNextYear() {

    $years = $this->getYears();
    foreach ($years as $key => $value) {
        $y[] = $value + 1;
    }
    return $y;
}
```

I display this in my index:

```
  <?php foreach ($years as $year): ?>

        <div class="">

            <?= $year; ?><br>

        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?><br>
```

It is possibe to add one year using only php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You will need use Ajax to load more content into your view.

Also, you will check if there is more years to load, then display a button that calls a Ajax with Javascript/Jquery. This request will put content directly into you page, with means, your function getNextYear(), must return a Json or Html content.

If the result is a Json, in AJax callback, format in HTML.

After all this, along with the button, put a div, with some class to put more content:

```
<button id="callAjaxNextYears"></button>
<div class="nextYears"></div>
```

Don't forget, in your ajax send the last year showed. Then you can use something like:

```
<button value="2012"></button>
```

And in your function, must to recognize a _GET or _POST or the the param:

```
getNextYear($start){}
```

---

As better practices, all this list of years must be implemented by ajax, to avoid a standard code in your project. Or, you can learn more about "AngularJS".

---

Try change your PHP function to work better with ajax call:

```
public $actualYear;
public $maxYear = 2030; // Just a exemple, otherwhise, will create infinite years list

public static function getYears() {

        if(isset($this->actualYear)){
            $nowYear = $this->actualYear;
        } else {
            $nowYear = date("Y");
            $this->actualYear = 2010;
        }

        if($nowYear < $maxYear){

            $i = 0;
            for ($yearNum = $this->actualYear; $yearNum <= $nowYear; $yearNum++) {
                $year[] = $yearNum;
                $i++;
                if ($i == 3)
                    break;
            }

        }

        return $year;
    }

public function getNextYear() {

    $this->actualYear = $_POST['start']; // Wherever your ajax has sended, can be a _GET as well

    $years = $this->getYears();
    foreach ($years as $key => $value) {
        $y[] = $value + 1;
    }
    return $y;
}
```

---

If you chose not use ajax, try this:

```
<a href="?start=2012">Load more years</a>
```

Then in controller:

```
public $maxYear = 2030; // Just a exemple, otherwhise, will create infinite years list

public static function getYears() {

        if(isset($_GET['start'])){
            $nowYear = $_GET['start'];
        } else {
            $nowYear = date("Y");
            $this->actualYear = 2010;
        }

        if($nowYear < $maxYear){

            $i = 0;
            for ($yearNum = $this->actualYear; $yearNum <= $nowYear; $yearNum++) {
                $year[] = $yearNum;
                $i++;
                if ($i == 3)
                    break;
            }

        }

        return $year;
    }
```

Comment: can u show me more details pls? what is this $start in my function? I want only change my first foreach in my index. In thi foreach i have $years after click I want have there $nextYear value

Comment: but what about button which change me function. I know that my functions work i checked this with var_dump i want only to know what can i do to make button which do some action to reload the page and show me result from second function

Comment: Well, without ajax and using just a button or a link, you can use <a href="?start=2012">Load more years</a> Then in your controller, deal the $_GET['start] as my $actualYear object exemple.